# What is difference between `command | cat > output.txt` and `command | > output.txt`

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

Why can't we direct these outputs into the file after route with Pipe?

You can understand much better what i mean by the example. In my example, why can't I route output with only the routing operator("`>`") without using the `cat` command?

**With `cat` command:**

```
└─$ whoami | cat > out.txt
└─$ cat out.txt
testter
```

**Without `cat` command:**

```
└─$ whoami | > out1.txt
└─$ cat out1.txt
#no any content in file..
└─$ whoami | >> out2.txt
└─$ cat out2.txt
#no any content in file..
```

I could also use an alternative tool instead of the `cat` command. It's not the `cat` tool that's important here. What I want to ask is why can't we route data coming directly from the pipe with the routing operator "`>`"?

Comment: Flabergasted that is not a syntax error. But you do know you can simply do `whoami > file`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way a pipe works conceptually, is that it connects the output of the left command to the input of the right command.

So the line:

```
whoami | cat > out.txt
```

`whoami` will print to `stdout` by default but since there is a pipe it will get connected to the input of `cat`.

So what does this mean?

```
whoami | > out.txt
```

Well, you are saying attach the output of `whoami` to nothing. Then redirect the output of nothing to the file `out.txt`

The `>` operator means trunc the file named as the right argument, creating it if necessary, then redirect the output of the left command to the file. Note that

```
> out.txt
```

will create an empty file.

Comment: Any idea why `whoami | ;` errors out then? It is essentially the same without a redirection, if I'm reading your answer correctly.

Comment: @Quasímodo my guess would be that the `|` requires something to attach to on both sides. So `A | ;` doesn't have a right command, but `A | > B` does, the `|` can connect to the input of `>` but you would have to check the grammar to be sure.

Comment: @Quasímodo Using "`> Out.txt`" is a valid procedure. But only "`;`" its use does not make sense for the shell. You can confirm this by entering both commands in your current console. When you use Pipe, `A | B` In the form of, processes **A** and **B** are executed in two separate subshells. Therefore, both processes **A** and **B** must be valid operations on the shell with alone. When only "`;`"  the operator is used, we get an error because it does not make sense on the shell.